# About Look Up Tables and Embedded Memory Blocks

Tags: fpga

Can anyone please explain me about the difference between LOOK UP TABLES and EMBEDDED MEMORY BLOCKS in FPGA. I've searched but didn't get any clarification on this..please help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Low effort question but I'll answer quickly anyway.

LUTs are (generally) the building blocks of modern SRAM FPGAs. With say a 6-LUT you can implement a large variety of digital logic primitives (AND, OR, NOT, XOR, Muxes...the list goes on, see the manufacturer docs.) It is worth noting that modern parts also usually provide a "free" flip-flop or similar along with this.

Embedded memory is high-performance SRAM implemented on the die, in various organizations (width X depth) for usage by on-chip logic. If you did not have this, you'd have to store bits in flip-flops (expensive utilization wise) or interface to an external memory device.

Example usage of embedded memory would be to hold FIR filter coefficients for a DSP implementation. Dedicated DSP blocks plus simple logic implemented via those LUTs would be a common design.

Comment: It would probably help clarify things to point out that a 6-LUT is another name for a 64-bit RAM, addressed one bit at a time. And that "distributed RAM" just means using these RAM as RAM instead of as logic.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup tables (a.k.a. "LUT"s) are tiny blocks of memory (typically 16×1 to 64×1) that are mostly used to implement logic. A "logic cell" generally contains a LUT and a flipflop.

Block RAMs are larger blocks of memory that are mostly used to hold data. They are typically on the order of 18K bits, with a variable organization that runs anywhere from 18K×1 to 512×36.

Most FPGAs have some amount of both types of memory.